# How to create a new array of objects from an array of values in an array of objects. TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array of dates in an array of objects like below. I wish to create a new array of objects base of each individual date. Spliting th dates and duplicate the rest of values into each date.

```
 const obj = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    dateTime: [
      {
        date: '26-10-1988',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '10:30'
      },
      {
        date: '27-10-1988',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '10:30'
      },
      {
        date: '29-10-1988',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '10:30'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    email: 'mary@email.com',
    dateTime: [
      {
        date: '26-10-1988',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '10:30'
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

*EDIT:

(There was a poor internet connection and somehow this question was submitted before I managed to complete it)

But here is the end result I'm looking for:

```
    const newObj = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    dateTime: {
      date: '26-10-1988',
      start: '10:00',
      end: '10:30'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    dateTime: {
      date: '27-10-1988',
      start: '10:00',
      end: '10:30'
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@email.com',
    dateTime: {
      date: '29-10-1988',
      start: '10:00',
      end: '10:30'
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Mary',
    email: 'mary@email.com',
    dateTime: {
      date: '26-10-1988',
      start: '10:00',
      end: '10:30'
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, you are expected to make your own attempt first at least.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Also, your verbal description of what you want as a result, is quite ambiguous IMHO. Add a proper example of what specific output you want based on the shown input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
const newArray = obj.map(i => {
  return i.dateTime.map(dateObj => {
    return {
      name: i.name,
      email: i.email,
      dateTime: dateObj
    };
  });
});

const resultArray = [].concat.apply([], newArray);

console.log(resultArray);
```

The `resultArray` will be (last item of array is expanded so you can check it):

[image: resultArray]

**EDIT**

You can achieve the same result with:

```
const resultArray = newArray.flat(1);
console.log(resultArray);
```